# Fragment not attached to a context, using getString Method

Tags: android

When I try to internationalize the App through xml / strings, I use getString Method to set the string to the variable in the Fragment. During the test, I did not send a crash, but it started to crash after the online update.

in sub fragment need override a variable:

```
        override val titleText: String get() = getString(R.string.string_goods_input_order_select_scan_waybill_num)
```

i find the getstring method use application.

```
    /**
     * Return a localized string from the application's package's
     * default string table.
     *
     * @param resId Resource id for the string
     */
    @NonNull
    public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
        return getResources().getString(resId);
    }
```

and the titleText is called in onViewCreated in the parent class, When I tested, there was no crash，but users update to new version，they cannot open the app.

this is crash log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment b{d85a8fe} not attached to a context.
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:31)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:0)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:0)
    at com.sfic.huaweiministorebarpistol.print.PrintSkuFragment.<init>(PrintSkuFragment.java:6)
    at com.sfic.huaweiministorebarpistol.print.PrintSkuFragment$Companion.a(PrintSkuFragment.java:2)
    at com.sfic.huaweiministorebarpistol.usercenter.UserCenterFragment$onViewCreated$8.onClick(UserCenterFragment.java:70)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6308)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24949)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:857)
```

i try to replace the **titleText: String**  with a method in the parent class:

```
abstract fun titleText(): String
```

and in the sub class

```
override fun titleText(): String {
    return getString(R.string.string_location_num)
}
```

At present, I guess it is because the context of getString is empty, but I did not reproduce the crash

Comment: use `return requireActivity().getResources().getString(resId);` instead

Comment: add code in UserCenterFragment, onViewCreated method, crash log said that, root cause is you getString before fragment attach to Host Activity

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

```
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:0)
at com.sfic.huaweiministorebarpistol.print.PrintSkuFragment.<init>(PrintSkuFragment.java:6)
```

So you're calling `getString()` when your `PrintSkuFragment` is being initialized. You cannot call `getString()` (or access variables such as your `get() = getString(...)`) when your Fragment is being constructed - they need to be initialized only after the fragment is attached (i.e., `onAttach()` is called).